# Use a request header with HTTP Client to external Api server

Tags: php, symfony

Consider the following request to a Symfony controller:

```
http http://127.0.0.1:8000/index x-token:1000
```

```php
#[Route('/index', name: 'index')]
public function index(HttpClientInterface $client, Request $request): Response
{
    $client->request('GET', 'http://0.0.0.0:3001', ['headers' => ['x-token' => $request->headers->get('x-token')]]);
    return new JsonResponse();
}
```

This code snippet is a minimal example for the usage in a controller. The controller accepts a Request, and uses the `x-token` header for authenticating against the 3rd Party Api (here: localhost:3001).

Is there a way, to automate this process? So basically - listen to incoming requests and inject the `x-token` header into a specific [Scoped Client](https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html#scoping-client) or the [default client](https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html#configuration) in Symfony.

The goal is, not to do this in every usage of the Http Client, but have a configured client service.

The client will be used all over the codebase, not just in a controller like in this minimal example.

I know that I can use [Service Decoration](https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html#extensibility) and extend the clients in use. I fail how to connect the dots and make this work.

Comment: If the endpoint that you are forwarding this on to supports forwarded headers per the specs, you might be able to use the trusted proxies option: https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment/proxies.html

Comment: @ChrisHaas I fail to see how proxy settings can help me to set the  authentication header when using the Symfony Http Client. I update my question and removed the term "forward". Obviously - I can miss something here ...

Comment: You could do the same on an event handler, before controller resolution. You'd still need to get the HTTP Client, and make the request. But you could at least centralize the process? Not very clear why you'd need to do this "on every controller usage", nor what exactly is the problem with the above approach. You simply want to have some configuration that so you can avoid writing those 2-3 lines of code?

Comment: @yivi I updated my question a little bit. Yes - the goal is to centralize this and not to "hand down" the authenticion token/the request when using the client in a controller or in a command handler. I'll look into the event handler idea.

Comment: It still not clear to me, sorry. What you want is to avoid setting the header each time you make the request? If you are simply proxying all requests that fulfil certain criteria, it doesn't follow that you need to use the client "all over the codebase". Good luck anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using [symfony kernel events](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html)?

First of all, if you are calling some 3rd-party api, I'd suggest you to create  a separate class at the infrastructure layer, for example `MyApiProvider`. Using HttpClient right from your controller is not smart, because you may also want to adjust something (for example api host, etc). So it's gonna look like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Infrastructure\Provider;

class MyApiProvider
{
    // Of course, this also be better configurable via your .env file
    private const HOST = 'http://0.0.0.0:3001';

    private HttpClientInterface $client;

    private ?string $token = null;

    public function __construct(HttpClientInterface $client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    public function setToken(string $token): void
    {
        $this->token = $token;
    }


    public function getSomething(): array
    {
        $response = $this->client->request(
            'GET',
            self::HOST,
            ['headers' => $this->getHeaders()]
        );

        return $response->toArray();
    }

    private function getHeaders(): array
    {
        $headers = [];
        if ($this->token !== null) {
            $headers['x-token'] = $this->token;
        }

        return $headers;
    }
}
```

Then you need to use symfony's `kernel.request` event to inject token to your provider from the request:

```
<?php

namespace App\Event;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\KernelEvent;

class RequestTokenEventListener
{
    private MyApiProvider $provider;

    public function __construct(MyApiProvider $provider)
    {
        $this->provider = $provider;
    }

    public function onKernelController(KernelEvent $event): void
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $token = $request->headers->get('x-token');

        if ($token !== null) {
            $this->provider->setToken($token);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally your controller:

```
#[Route('/index', name: 'index')]
public function index(MyApiProvider $provider): Response
{
    $provider->getSomething();

    return new JsonResponse();
}
```

So your provider is gonna have token context during each request, if the token is passed.